# Cycle through div background colors onClick with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change a div background color to a different color depending on what the div's current color is, when the div is clicked on. The following code does not work. I've figured it has something to do with my "if" statements because it works fine if I just make them change to 1 color with no "if" statements.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setColor(blockId) {
    if (document.getElementById(blockId).style.background == '#FF0000') {
        document.getElementById(blockId).style.background = '#0000FF';
    }else if (document.getElementById(blockId).style.background == '#0000FF') {
        document.getElementById(blockId).style.background = '#999999';
    }else if (document.getElementById(blockId).style.background == '#999999') {
        document.getElementById(blockId).style.background = '#FF0000';
    }
}
</script>

<div id="b1" style="background-color:#FF0000; height:100px; width:100px;" onClick="setColor('b1')"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increment an index to identify which background you are using from a list of backgrounds.  You can store that index as a property on the element.

```js
var backgrounds = ["#0000FF", "#999999", "#FF0000"];
function setColor(el) {
    el.colorIdx = el.colorIdx || 0;
    el.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[el.colorIdx++ % backgrounds.length];
}
```

Also, rather than doing a lookup on that element via `document.getElementById()`, just pass `this` from the `onclick` handler, and your function has a reference to the element itself.

```html
<div onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
```

Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/vPMPb/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is because of inconcistencies in how the `style.background` property is understood by the browser.  In some browsers `style.backgroundColor` (use this instead of `style.background` btw) will be "#FF0000" while in others it will be "#ff000" and in others "rgb(255,0,0)".  so checking the string won't work for you.  I suggest instead storing the color values in an array and keeping a global position variable.  Every time the div is clicked, incriment the index and use the array.  Similar to this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sp7St/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/sp7St/)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var colors = ["#FF0000","#0000FF","#999999"];
    var idx = 0;

function setColor(blockId) {
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.backgroundColor = colors[++idx%3];
}
</script>

<div id="b1" style="background-color:#FF0000; height:100px; width:100px;" onClick="setColor('b1')"></div>
```

EDIT: btw, the `++idx%3` is just `++idx` (increment before evaluating) and `%3` (modulos 3, which is "the remainder of the value divided by 3")

Comment: Any suggestions on how to set that up if I have more then one div on the same page that needs to cycle colors on click?

Comment: @Mark I like the way gilly3 did it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not your logic.  Presentation properties cannot be inferred from the DOM unless the properties are resident in a style attribute on the given DOM element node.  Just supply a background color to the targeted HTML tag using a style attribute in the static HTML.  Now your JavaScript and detect the background color property and performed as designed.